# Service method to store image for two different picture category

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a project to store images for Rental property. The images would be for Bedroom and Bathroom.

| Rental |
| --- |
| BedroomImageId |
| BathroomImageId |

```
// Service class method
public void uploadRentalImage(Long rentalId, MultipartFile file) {
     String imageId = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); // BedroomPictureId or BathroomPictureId will be created here
     // Then store the imageId to Rental; depending on whether it is BedroomPictureId or BathroomPictureId
}
```

I have two logics depedning on whether the image is BathroomImageId and BedroomImageId which I need to tell the uploadRentalImage. I have various ways in mind to tell the uploadRentalImage method as to which image I am updating. Could anyone recommend the best way of telling uploadRentalImage what type of image I am updating.

I could create two service class method like below but it would have too much of same logic repeating in both methods and is not scalable in future if I were to have more types of images like GarageImage or CourtyardImage.

```
public void uploadRentalImage(Long rentalId, MultipartFile file) {
     String imageId = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); // BedroomPictureId or BathroomPictureId will be created here
     rentalDao.updateBedroomImageId(bedroomImageId, rentalId);
}
public void uploadBathroomImage(Long rentalId, MultipartFile file) {
     String imageId = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); // BedroomPictureId or BathroomPictureId will be created here
     rentalDao.updateBedroomImageId(bedroomImageId, rentalId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `RentalImage` class to store the reference to your images and `ImageCategory` enum to categorize your images, such as:

```
public class RentalImage {
    private Long imageId;
    private String imageName;
    private String imageUrl;
    private ImageCategory category;
}

public enum ImageCategory {
   BEDROOM,
   BATHROOM
}
```

And, you can pass `RentalImage` object to the `uploadRentalImage` method. Now, this object has all the information needed to categorize the image.

Comment: Thank you @hermit. I will try your suggestion and give you an update.

Comment: Hi @hermit So I have the Rental Class with a 'one to many' relationship with RentalImage class but then how do I limit the rental class to have a rental image of just 'one' BEDROOM ImageCategory and not 'more'. The pictures are suppose to be just one per category. For eg. I do not want a Rental Object to have more than one RentalImage object of BEDROOM Imagecategory. Do I have to put this logic in the Service class?

Comment: How have you defined the relationship between Rental class and RentalImage class? Generally, rental image(child) will have id of the rental class(parent). And, you can add a validation logic in your code such as:

isImageExists(rentalId, ImageCategory category);

Basically, this method checks if there is already a rental image image for rental class with id rentalId for a given category.